# Get the data from bound combobox

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I m facing problem to get value of combobox which is bound from database

```
 `String stri = "Select [Interest] from tbl_Interests";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(stri, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds,"tbl_Interests");
            cmbTypeofList.DataSource = ds.Tables["tbl_Interests"];
            cmbTypeofList.ValueMember = "Interest";`
```

calling it 
`string intr = cmbTypeofList.SelectedItem.ToString();`
`string intr = cmbTypeofList.SelectedValue.ToString();`
in the both above conditions i m getting the selected value as System.Data.DataRowView

`string intr = cmbTypeofList.SelectedText;`
if i m giving the above way i m getting "" null value

How to get the selected value of the combobox in C# windowsapp

Comment: check your querry return some data or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the data in comboBox C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733223/how-to-get-the-data-in-combobox-c)

Comment: Thank you Jason now solved my prob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the display member and value membr of combobox to appropriate field name
Take a look to this link [How to set values into ComboBox Items](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/valuemembersample.aspx)