# How to get the data in comboBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a combo box and I populated it this way:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (SQLiteConnection conn = connection.Conn)
{               
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select id, description from category";
        conn.Open();

        using (SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(dtChargeCodes);
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "description";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
        }                                       
    }               
}
```

What I'm trying to achive is to get the data of the selected item in the comboBox but when I tried to display it using `MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());` what I get is the type `System.Data.DataRowView.` not the actual value of the field description in the table category. Please help... thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use

```
comboBox1.SelectedText
```

or

```
((System.Data.DataRowView)(comboBox1.SelectedItem))["description"]
```

You may need to use the second method if you need to access the value in the SelectedIndexChanged event (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx))

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: this will display the `id` value from the query "select id, description from category". not the description....

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the question properly. Normally the value is what you're after.

Comment: Try Patrick McDonald's way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733223/how-to-get-the-data-in-combobox-c/6733452#6733452

Answer (score 2):

I think you need

```
MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString())
```

Comment: I think there's no `Value` property for `ComboBox.Selected`.

Comment: The problem is, I think, that you are getting the item. There should be some property on the item that gives you the value. Sorry - I don't have access to an environment to check ATM.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the screen value use this:

```
MessageBox.Show(combobox1.SelectedText);
```

Comment: Note: If DropDownStyle is set to DropDownList, the return value is an empty string ("").

Answer (score 1):

Some explanation:

```
MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()); //get selected item value
MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.Text); //get selected item text
```